# Data loads for a very long time and the data is not displayed in RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, retrofit

I have a RecyclerView where a set of groups must be displayed. Now the progress bar is shown for a long time and the groups are not displayed. I am using the retrofit for fetching the groups. The progress bar loads for a long time and when the progress bar Visibility becomes gone. No data has been displayed.

This is the java file

```
 private void getAllGroups(int offset, int limit) {
    if (offset == 0) {
        relativeLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } else {
        loadLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    Call<List<TrendingGroupsResponse>> allGroupsCall = retrofit.getAllMajorGroups(String.valueOf(offset), String.valueOf(limit));
    Callback<List<TrendingGroupsResponse>> allGroupsCallBack = new Callback<List<TrendingGroupsResponse>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<List<TrendingGroupsResponse>> call, Response<List<TrendingGroupsResponse>> response) {

            if (response.body() != null) {

                Gson gson = new Gson();
                Log.d(TAG, gson.toJson(response.body()));

                for (TrendingGroupsResponse response1 : response.body())
                    allGroupsList.add(new SelectionGroupItem(response1));

                if (response.body().size() < limit) {
                    reachedEnd = true;
                }
                loadmore = true;

                if (offset == 0) {
                    allGroupsAdapter = new GroupSelectionTrendingAdapter(getApplicationContext(),
                            allGroupsList, GroupSelectionActivity.this, ALL_GROUPS_MODE);

                    allGroups.setAdapter(allGroupsAdapter);

                } else if (allGroupsAdapter != null) 
                    allGroupsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }

                groupSelectLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                mainlayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                relativeLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                loadLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<List<TrendingGroupsResponse>> call, Throwable t) {


            View view = findViewById(R.id.root_view);
            Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(view, "Network Error", Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE)
                    .setAction("RELOAD", new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View view) {
                            getTrendingGroups();
                            getAllGroups(offset, limit);
                        }
                    });
            snackbar.show();

        }
    };
    allGroupsCall.enqueue(allGroupsCallBack);
}
```

How can I resolve this so that data is loaded and displayed?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try to declare the adapter above all the method calling (like on the `onCreate()` method of your `GroupSelectionActivity`)

```
allGroupsAdapter = new GroupSelectionTrendingAdapter(
    getApplicationContext(), 
    new ArrayList<SelectionGroupItem>(), 
    GroupSelectionActivity.this, 
    ALL_GROUPS_MODE
);

// Considering allGroups is your RecyclerView
allGroups.setAdapter(allGroupsAdapter);
```

Then, in `GroupSelectionTrendingAdapter` expose a method `updateData(List<SelectionGroupItem> items)`

```
@UiThread
public void updateData(List<SelectionGroupItem> newItems) {
    /** 
     * this.selectionGroupItems is a property of GroupSelectionTrendingAdapter 
     * that is used to display the data. 
     *
     * It is init in the constructor, then it never changes 
     * and is never reset using the = operator
     */ 
    this.selectionGroupItems.clear()
    this.selectionGroupItems.addAll(newItems)
    // On the UI thread, as it is updating UI items.
    this.notifyDataSetChanged()
}
```

And then in your callback:

```
if (response.body() != null) {
    // ...
    for (TrendingGroupsResponse response1 : response.body())
        allGroupsList.add(new SelectionGroupItem(response1));

    // not needed anymore if (offset == 0) {

    // Call is wrapped to run on the UI thread
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            allGroupsAdapter.updateData(allGroupsList);
        }
    });

    // ...
}
```

This way the adapter never changes, it is set at the very beginning of the life of your screen. 
The only thing that changes is the data your displaying within.

The [`runOnUiThread`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread(java.lang.Runnable)) is there to ensure the call is made on the displaying thread

N.B. Also, I'm not sure why you are giving `getApplicationContext()` to your adapter as `GroupSelectionActivity.this` is also a context.
Please remind to not keep references of activities within views that can be destroyed keeeping the reference (memory leaks)